# How to save connections with Remmina 1.2.0?

Tags: remmina

Someone else asked a similar question in April (here: [Remmina 1.2 Save Connection](https://askubuntu.com/questions/909575/remmina-1-2-save-connection)), but there were no responses.  I didn’t see a way to amplify the question, as opposed to providing an answer.  So, I’m asking again and hope I don’t get flamed.

Short story:  Can’t create/save a connection with Remmina 1.2.0-rcgit-19

Longer explanation:  I run Remnima 1.1.2 on Ubuntu 16.04 Desktop and it works just fine.  I have two connections created and saved.  To create a new one, one clicks on the icon with “Create a new remote desktop file”.

I created a Vmware Player virutal machine, also Ubuntu 16.04.  I opened the Ubuntu Software application and removed Remmina 1.1.2.  Remmina 1.2.0 was available via Ubuntu Software and I installed it.  I can create a ‘quick connect’ and RDP to a system on my home network.  It connects and works fine.

What I can’t do is – create and save connections.

The icon “+” brings up a dialog box and I can fill in all the requested info.  However the “Save” button is grayed out.

Per the FAQ, I checked for the location of the profiles (remmina.pref) and came up empty.  I finally found the remmina.pref file in “~/snap/remmina/174/.config/remmina”.  I copied a remote desktop file to that folder (123456789.remmina [or whatever]) and fired up remmina.  Nope, it’s not found/listed.  I also did “touch x.x” and it was just fine.  I have write access to the folder.

So, I’m puzzled on where/how to create and keep a connection.  All I can see to do is quick connect.

Comment: For me the save button will be active as soon as you change Name from "Quick connect" to something else. It does not even needs a username or anything else. Just a new name.

Comment: make it an answer ;)

Comment: @Rinzwind why did you not made it an answer?

Comment: @Roland you are missing context. There was a comment in between my 2 comments and Brendan made the answer himself. I deleted my answer after he made his ;-)

Comment: @Rinzwind Confusing. Probably to do with combining 2 questions: on saving, and on passwords. Should be 2 separate SO questions. Combining questions smells like trying to save paper, but this is the digital age :-)

Answer (score 1):

Nod to Rinzwind for pointing me to change my comments to an answer.

First, thank you, Rinzwind. That worked. Kind of a 'duh' moment for me. Second, I couldn't get the password to save. As I googled for this it looks like there is a 'snap' and keyring integration problem/bug. For those who may follow -- I removed Remmina via Ubuntu Software center. I then reinstalled Remmina via a PPA (visit github.com/FreeRDP/Remmina/wiki). Now after entering a password, they are correctly saved.

Comment: You won't earn any points with "accepting" your own answer, but it will indicate to others that this solved the problem. The password problem could have been a separate question and answer.